# Force Table To Store Text Data in Upper Case Characters

Tags: ms-access

I want to force all data in certain columns to be stored as Upper Case characters. Is there a way to do this? When I put > in the format property, it displays it as capital letters but does not actually store it that way. If I click on the field, it reverts to lower case if it was entered as lower case.

Answer (score 0):

Have to use code behind form to convert user input to all upper case. Use textbox AfterUpdate event. VBA example:

```
Private Sub tbxFieldPL_AfterUpdate()
Me.tbxFieldPL = UCase(Me.tbxFieldPL)
End Sub
```

This can only be done with a text type field, not date/time. If you want to display date/time with month in upper case, calculate with UCase() and Format() functions in query or textbox on report. Don't bother in table or form. The result will be a text string, not an actual date/time value.